# Disable SplitTunneling

Tags: powershell, vpn

I'm trying to trun-off split tunneling in VPN client for all domain users.I ran the command locally on one of the client for testing and got below error. The VPN connection does exists on the client machine and the connection name is correct.

The `"Use default gateway on remote network"` checkbox is `unchecked`(split tunneling enabled) in VPN adapter properties.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Set-VpnConnection -Name "XXXX" 
      -AllUserConnection -SplitTunneling:$false
```

> Set-VpnConnection :  The configuration cannot be applied to the global
>   user VPN connection XXXX. : The system could not find the phone book
>   entry for this connection. At line:1 char:1
>   + Set-VpnConnection -Name "xxxx" -AllUserConnection -SplitTunneling: ...
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (XXXX:root/Microsoft/...S_VpnConnection) [Set-VpnConnection], CimExce 
>   ption
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : VPN 623,Set-VpnConnection

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Use formatting tools to make your post more readable. Code block should look like `code block`. Use **bold** *italics* if needed.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It is community edited. This means that if you see a way that a question or answer can be edited to be better, you can do it!